# Android to WCF POST throws "Internal Server Error"

Tags: android, .net, wcf, rest, post

I am trying to send an image from android to a .NET based server. My requirement is to send an image from android device to .NET based server using HTTP and REST.I am getting an error :-
"org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error"

The following is the logcat out put:-

```
10-22 14:08:53.703: W/System.err(652): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
10-22 14:08:53.703: W/System.err(652):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
10-22 14:08:53.712: W/System.err(652):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
10-22 14:08:53.712: W/System.err(652):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
10-22 14:08:53.712: W/System.err(652):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
10-22 14:08:53.712: W/System.err(652):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
10-22 14:08:53.722: W/System.err(652):  at com.example.imageupload.RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:64)
10-22 14:08:53.747: W/System.err(652):  at com.example.imageupload.RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-22 14:08:53.752: W/System.err(652):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-22 14:08:53.752: W/System.err(652):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-22 14:08:53.762: W/System.err(652):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-22 14:08:53.762: W/System.err(652):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
10-22 14:08:53.772: W/System.err(652):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
10-22 14:08:53.782: W/System.err(652):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

The code is as follows:-

Android :-

```
package com.example.imageupload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    File mImageFile;
    String SERVICE_URL_UPLOAD_PICTURE = "http://10.0.2.2:1000/Service1.svc/UploadImage/";
    String IMAGE_FILE_NAME            = "android.jpg";  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new RequestTask().execute(SERVICE_URL_UPLOAD_PICTURE.concat(IMAGE_FILE_NAME));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}

class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

        String responseString           =   "";     

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient    =   new DefaultHttpClient();
        String WebUri                   =   uri[0].toString();
        URI WebURI                      =   URI.create(WebUri);
        HttpPost httppost               =   new HttpPost(WebURI);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        File myfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/android.jpg"); 

        try{
            MultipartEntity entity      =   new MultipartEntity();

            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(myfile, "image/jpeg"));
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            responseString              =    httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

WCF code:-

Service1.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace WcfImageUpload
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public void UploadImage(string filename, System.IO.Stream image)
        {
            FileStream fileToUpload = new FileStream("C:\\" + filename, FileMode.Create);
            byte[] bytearray    = new byte[1000000];

            int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = image.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);

                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            } while (bytesRead > 0);

            fileToUpload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
            fileToUpload.Close();
            fileToUpload.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

IService1.cs:-

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfImageUpload
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.

    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
              UriTemplate = "/UploadImage/{filename}")]
        void UploadImage(string filename, System.IO.Stream image);
    }
}
```

Web.config:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <services>
            <service name="WcfImageUpload.Service1"
                     behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" >
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://somesite.com:5555/Service1/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint name="Service1"
                          address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="WcfImageUpload.IService1" 
                          behaviorConfiguration="web"/>

                <endpoint name="LoginServiceMex"
                          address="mex"
                          binding="mexHttpBinding"
                          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```